# Having problems using Hensel Lifting for Prime Power Moduli

Tags: number-theory

We have $P(x) = x^2 + 3x + 9 ≡ 0 \mod(3^i)$, for $i=1,2,3,4$

for $\mod(3): x^2 + 3x + 9 ≡ x^2$, so $x ≡ 0 \mod(3)$ is a solution.

From Hensel lifting, we have $s = x + a\times 7,\ a = [-P(0)\times (1/3)] \times (P'(0))^{-1}$.
Computing for $a$, we get $a = -3 \times (3)^{-1}$. But, $(3)^{-1}$ is when $3a ≡ 1 \mod(3)$, but this has no solutions since $\gcd(3,3)$ is not $1$. Where am I going wrong? Can somebody help me out please? :(

Comment: It helps potential responders if you format the math expressions in the question using TeX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We go through the lifting process. The case $i=1$ has been dealt with. We now deal with $i=2$. Let $p=3$. Instead of $i$ we will use $k$.

We have $P'(x)=2x+3$. This is congruent to $0$ modulo $p$. In that case, the Hensel lifting goes as follows:

1) If we have a root $a$ modulo $p^k$, and $p^{k+1}$ divides $P(a)$, then the root $a$ modulo $p^k$ lifts to $p$ roots modulo $p^{k+1}$;

2) If $p^{k+1}$ does not divide $P(a)$, then the root $a$ does not lift to a root modulo $p^{k+1}$.

Currently we are lifting from $k=1$, with $a=0$. Note that $p^2$ divides $P(a)$, so by 1) the root $a=0$ lifts to $3$ roots modulo $p^2$, namely $a\equiv 0$, $3$, or $6$ modulo $9$.

Now we lift from $k=2$ to $k=3$. First look at $a\equiv 0\pmod{9}$. We have $P(0)\equiv 9\not\equiv 0\pmod{3^3}$, so the root $a\equiv 0\pmod{9}$ does not lift. A similar argument shows that $a\equiv 6\pmod{9}$ does not lift.

Now look at the root $a\equiv 3\pmod{9}$. The number $P(3)$ is divisible by $3^3$, so the root $a\equiv 3\pmod{9}$ lifts to $3$ solutions modulo $3^3$, namely $a\equiv 3$, $12$, and $21$ modulo $3^3$.

We now have $3$ roots modulo $3^3$. For each of them, we investigate liftability to a solution modulo $3^4$. So calculate $P(3)$, $P(12)$, and $P(21)$.

I expect you can now continue, and finish the analysis for $k=4$. As a start, the root $a\equiv 3\pmod{3^3}$ does not lift.

**Remark:** Since we are only asked to go to the small number $3^4$, there are less tedious ways to proceed than Hensel lifting. We went through the process on the assumption that this is the tool you were asked to use.

Since our polynomial is a quadratic, another way to proceed for *general* $k$ is to multiply by $4$. We get the equivalent congruence $4x^2+12x+36\equiv 0\pmod{3^k}$. Complete the square, and rewrite as $(2x+3)^2\equiv -27\pmod{3^k}$.

Comment: I have just worked on k=4 and it seems like none of the three roots a ≡ 3, 12, 21 mod(27) works for k=4. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Look at my congruence $(2x+3)^2\equiv -27\pmod{3^k}$ of the Remark. Take $k=4$, or bigger. For the congruence to hold, $2x+3$ must be divisible by $9$. But then $(2x+3)^2$ is divisible by $81$, so cannot be congruent to $-27$ modulo $81$, or any higher power of $3$.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to use a formula that is only valid when $P'(0)\not\equiv0\pmod3$. In this case, the derivative vanishes at the root in question, so Hensel lifting is more complicated (see [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hensel%27s_lemma#Hensel_Lifting) for a brief description).